# error in get data from access database to datagridview Vb.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

i have a problem when i click to item in datagridview to get more information ! ok ?
my code :

```
Try
        If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0) Then Return
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox3.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox4.Text = String.Empty
        Dim id As String = DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT items.ClientName, items.ClientAddress, items.ClientPhone, items.ClientCredit, items.ClientLastPay FROM items where items.ClientID = {0}", id))
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        TextBox3.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
        TextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString
        dt.Dispose()
        dt = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

by debugging the error is in this line :

`Dim id As String = DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString`

thats my full source code http://up.dev-point.com/download279606.html

Comment: What's with that link?

Comment: thats the source code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the DataGridView like an array, when you need to specify that you're looking in the rows and columns. Instead of

```
DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value
```

you can write

```
DataGridView1.Columns(2).Cells(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value
```

However, relying on SelectedRows is not the best way to do it. What if the user accidentally selected a few rows and clicked the bottom one?

Assuming your code is in a CellClick handler with

```
(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
```

you should use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs to tell what row you're on instead of relying on SelectedRows:

```
Dim id As String = DataGridView1(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
```

Comment: i have an error in this code : `DataGridView1.Columns(2).Cells(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value`  **'Cells' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'**

Comment: and also i have error in this code `Dim id As String = DataGridView1(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value` error : **Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' accepts this number of arguments.**